# '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'CString'

Tags: c++, casting

This code was written in Visual Studio 2003, but now I compile it in 2008.

```
int AFXAPI AfxMessageBox(LPCTSTR lpszText, UINT nType = MB_OK, UINT nIDHelp = 0);

if(iiRecd == SOCKET_ERROR || iiRecd == 0) {
  iErr = ::GetLastError();
  AfxMessageBox(CString(iErr));
  goto PreReturnCleanup;
}
```

In 2003, it works fine, but in 2008, it shows me an error:

> Error 50 error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'CString'

What does this error mean?

Comment: Can you show us the line of code where the error is?

Comment: As Armen Tisrunyan observed, no more that what the error message already says can be said without seeing the offending code.

Comment: I'm always surprised about people who think that it _is_ relevant that the error was on line 4539 of mysocket.cpp. We'd give the same answer if it was on line 3, really. Or if the source file was stored on the C:\ drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard to help without any information, like the erroneous code and what you want to do there.

Here's a guess:
You want to convert an `int` to a `CString`, somehow like this:

```
int i = 42;
CString str = (CString)i;
```

If you're using the [MFC/ATL CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea%28VS.80%29.aspx) you could try the following

```
int i = 42;
CString str;
str.Format("%d", i);
```

[CString::Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) takes a format string like `printf` and stores the result in the CString.

### Edit

I'm interpreting your comment below as the code that causes the error. A bit surrounding text and explanation would be nice, though.

```
if(iiRecd == SOCKET_ERROR || iiRecd == 0) { 
  iErr = ::GetLastError();
  AfxMessageBox(CString(iErr));
  goto PreReturnCleanup; 
}
```

Try to change it to

```
if(iiRecd == SOCKET_ERROR || iiRecd == 0) { 
  iErr = ::GetLastError();
  CString msg;
  msg.Format("%d", iErr);
  AfxMessageBox(msg);
  goto PreReturnCleanup; 
}
```

One general comment on the `goto PreReturnCleanup;`: You may want to take a look at the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)-Idiom as a (imho) better way to do such cleanup.

Comment: check this line of code.....actually these code written in Visual studio 2003 and now i compile it in 2008...in 2003 it work fine but in 2008 it showing me error


int AFXAPI AfxMessageBox(LPCTSTR lpszText, UINT nType = MB_OK,
    UINT nIDHelp = 0);


 if(iiRecd == SOCKET_ERROR || iiRecd == 0)
  {
      iErr = ::GetLastError();
   AfxMessageBox(CString(iErr));
    goto PreReturnCleanup;
  }

Comment: int AFXAPI AfxMessageBox(LPCTSTR lpszText, UINT nType = MB_OK,
    UINT nIDHelp = 0);

Comment: @tirupati: Please add your code to the original question. And make sure it's formatted (there's a `110110` button to format selected text)

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously because you used an expression of type `int` where an expression of type `CString` was expected. No more can be said without further code.